# What do you do if you made a Tzedaka pledge and now the organization folded?

Tags: halacha, money, tzedakah-charity, nedarim-shevuot, yeshiva-school

Recently a friend of mine asked me the following question. He pledged $500- to a Yeshiva, yet before he paid the pledge the Yeshiva closed. Does he still have to pay his pledge to another Tzedaka or is he absolved? Is there a difference if the Tzedaka closed and remained in debt or if it closed and satisfied all outstanding debts? Is there a difference if the organization had bylaws specifying what happens to their assets on dissolution? (As always CYLOR)

Comment: Just wondering, why doesn't he just do Hatarat Nedarim to take himself out of any Safek?

Comment: Can't remember the source, but he doesn't pay to the other Sedaka.

Comment: Maybe it is necessary to do Hataras Nedarim, maybe he has to pay to a similar charity, maybe he has to do nothing.

Comment: Speculation: if the organization had bylaws specifying what happens to their assets on dissolution (as I suspect most do if they have a board and a bank account), perhaps he owes his pledge to the designated recipient?

Comment: Who else read the title quickly and thought the question was closed?

Comment: On a similar note as @MonicaCellio, The Yeshiva may still have debts even if they are no longer in business.

Comment: I've recently heard of a non-profit that is thinking of dissolving because of debt it owes, and reopening with a similar board and the same purpose but as a new legal entity under a new name and bylaws. I suppose your question can be extended to "would I need to redirect the money to the new organization?".

Comment: I once asked a Posek if an organization has to return money that was extra for that specific project they were trying to fund, and he said they must return the extra funds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://halachafortoday.com/QandA4.aspx

> A: The Chazon Ish ruled that one who made up his mind to give Tzedaka
>   to a certain poor person who was collecting, and  then the poor person
>   disappeared (similar to your case of the organization closing down)
>   you can give the money to a different poor person (or in your case a
>   similar institution)   The best thing to do always when pledging
>   Tzedaka is to say it's "Bli Neder", thus if you run into issues you
>   will not have a promise to deal with. (Psak of Rav Shlomo Zalmen
>   Auerbach Zatzal)