# What if the Gabbai Tzedakah runs away?

Tags: halacha, money, tzedakah-charity, nedarim-shevuot

Suppose a Gabbai Tzedakah passes our good friend Reuven while making his collection rounds. Reuven reaches into his pocket for his wallet and removes the money he wants to donate. By the time Reuven lifts his eyes, the Gabbai is gone.

What should Reuven now do with the money he separated for Tzedakah? Is he allowed to keep it? Can he give it to some other Tzedakah?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you do if you made a Tzedaka pledge and now the organization folded?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/what-do-you-do-if-you-made-a-tzedaka-pledge-and-now-the-organization-folded)

Comment: differs in that here the giver may be able to still give it to the same guy.

Comment: @HodofHod True. Just realized I was focusing on the answer there...

Comment: that answer might not even apply here, since there it might be that it's impossible to find the poor man, but not so here.